# SQL - Multiple 'THEN' options in a 'CASE WHEN' statement

Tags: sql, case

I need to use a CASE WHEN statement in my query with multiple 'THEN' options.
So something like this:

```
...
WHERE
region = CASE WHEN @cbEU = 'true' **THEN 0 OR 1**
              ELSE 2 END
```

Or perhaps something like:

```
...
 WHERE
 region IN CASE WHEN @cbEU = 'true' **THEN (0,1)**
                ELSE (1,2) END
```

I don't suppose there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: Try to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also, it's a case expression, not a case statement. (The case expression has a return value. The case statement is conditional execution of code, to be used in stored procedures etc.)

Comment: what are you trying to achive?

Comment: I am trying to say in the where clause - `if @cbEU = 'true' then WHERE region = 0 OR region = 1`  That is the logic I am trying to achieve but can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: You don't use `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause. The `CASE` expression provides a way to write a condition (e.g. in the `SELECT` clause), but the `WHERE` clause is a condition already. Simply use `AND`and `OR` plus parentheses if needed in `WHERE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
WHERE ((@cbEU = 'true') AND region IN (0, 1)) OR 
      ((@cbEU = 'false') AND region IN (1, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code which i wrote to answer your query :

```
 Create Table Test 
 (
   a int, 
   b varchar(10) 
 )

 Insert into Test Values (1,'Sample1'),(2,'Sample2'),(3,'Sample3'),                           
 (4,'Sample4'),(5,'Sample5')

 Declare @input int = 2 

 SELECT * from Test where 
 b =
 CASE @input 
 when 1 then 'Sample1'
 when 2 then 'Sample2' 
 when 3 then 'Sample3'
END
```

Output :

a | b

2 | Sample2

Case statement is pretty useful in scenarios like yours. It can be used in select, update, where , having, OrderBy, Delete statements.

Reference :

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/1MS1120313-Understanding-Case-Expression-in-SQL-Server-with-Example.html